# Looking for a way to get around querySelector just selecting the first element or class

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to do a "To-Do List", just to see what I've learned so far, and what I'm stuck on is adding an event listener to the first input of the To-Do list, so when someone presses enter it creates a new Input which it automatically switches to so you can start writing another task.

Everything good until there, but here comes the BIG problem, as some of you might've guessed, when I try to actually press return on the newly created input, nothing really happens.

I tried with `querySelectorAll()` but just couldn't figure something out. I told a friend of mine not to tell me how to do it just for the sake of actually doing it, but since I'm currently learning, I'd rather understand why it works that way.

The starting HTML file looks like this

```
<body>
    <div class="to-do-wrapper">
        <ul class="list">
            <li id="new-list"> <i class="fas fa-check" id="checkmark" style="display: none;"></i> <input type="text" placeholder="Add a new Item" class="input-new-list"></input> <i class="fas fa-times" id="remove" style="display: none;"></i></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
```

```
let counter = 1;

document.querySelector('.input-new-list').addEventListener("keypress", function(e){
    let key = e.keyCode;
    let list = document.querySelector('.list');
    let newRow = document.createElement("li");
    let addInput = document.createElement('input');
    addInput.setAttribute('id', 'current-' + counter);
    addInput.setAttribute('class', 'input-new-list');
    addInput.setAttribute('type', 'text');
    newRow.setAttribute('id', 'new-list');
    // On press Return, new list
    if (key === 13) {
        list.appendChild(newRow);
        newRow.appendChild(addInput);
        document.getElementById('current-' + counter).focus();
        counter++;
    }
});
```

As I said above I'd like to be able to press Return (Enter) key, on any of the inputs created, to be able to create another input, on which it would focus by using the `getElementById` and `.focus()`. I know this is probably not the best way to write this but I'm just a month in with JS.

Comment: What is your starting HTML?

Comment: Please post all relevant code in the question itself, not on an external site. The error is: `Uncaught ReferenceError: removeButton is not defined` - looks like you never defined it

Comment: My question is not about removeButton, but about the inputs. Thanks for your answer. If I press return on the first Input, which is the one querySelector gets, it will create a new input, but if I press Return Key on any of the other inputs, nothing happens.

Comment: you have only one listener placed on the first input. the other created has no  event listerner added for them

Comment: @MrJ Yes, this was my point, how do I add eventlisteners to all the inputs, since querySelector won't allow me to do that?

Comment: bad way : addInput.addEventListerner ....  Good way : use event delegation

Comment: Are you using any other frameworks, like JQuery etc?

Answer (score 0):

I've made what appear to be a lot of changes, but it's really quite similar. I have:

1. used a event listener to tell us when document as finished loading
2. Look for input element and add event listener
3. Thrown-away the horrible `event.keyCode==13` in preference of `event.key=='Enter'`
4. Relied-upon the fact that the default type of input is a text input
5. used the `classList` interface instead of the `.setAttribute('class', xxx` method
6. Entirely thrown away use of a counter. It provides nothing of use to me - I don't need it to focus the new input or collect info from the rest. It's unnecessary.

Here's a working sample:

```js
"use strict";
function byId(id){return document.getElementById(id)}
function qsa(sel,par=document){return par.querySelectorAll(sel)}
function newEl(tag){return document.createElement(tag)}

window.addEventListener('load', onLoaded, false);
function onLoaded(evt)
{
 qsa('input')[0].addEventListener('keypress', inputElemKeypress, false);
 qsa('button')[0].addEventListener('click', onShowAllClicked, false);
}

function inputElemKeypress(evt)
{
 if (evt.key == 'Enter') // keyCode == 13
 {
  let tgtContainer = qsa('ul.list')[0];
  let newRow = newEl('li');
  let newInput = newEl('input');
  newInput.addEventListener('keypress', inputElemKeypress, false);
  newInput.classList.add('input-new-list');
  newRow.appendChild(newInput);
  tgtContainer.appendChild(newRow);
  newInput.focus();
 }
}

function onShowAllClicked(evt)
{
 var inputs = Array.from( qsa('input.input-new-list') );
 var result = '';
 
 inputs.forEach( 
     function(element, index, collection)
     {
      result += `[${index+1}] - ${element.value}<br>`;
     }
    );
 qsa('output')[0].innerHTML = result;
}
```

```html
<button>Show all items</button></br>
    <div class="to-do-wrapper">
        <ul class="list">
            <li id="new-list"> <i class="fas fa-check" id="checkmark" style="display: none;"></i> <input type="text" placeholder="Add a new Item" class="input-new-list"></input> <i class="fas fa-times" id="remove" style="display: none;"></i></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
 <output></output>
```

Comment: I have no view on it, but why is `key` better than `keyCode`?

Comment: @Halfer - Readability. Everyone knows which one is the Enter key. Lots of people know that scan-code 13 is used for that key. One group is clearly larger than the other. ;)